# How can a scala closure to be serialized and executed remotely, and assign the computed variables back to the variables located in the local closure

Tags: scala, serialization, closures, apache-spark

e.g. I have a closure defined in the client:

```
def runJob[T, U] (): Array[U] = {
    val results = new Array[U](100)
    submitJob[T, U]((index, res) => results(index) = res)
    results
}
```

Firstly, how can I serialize the `(index, res) => results(index) = res` function in the `submitJob` function?
Secondly, if I have executed the deserialized function at the remote end, how can I assign the remote `results` back to the `results` in the local closure?

Comment: For the same concern, spores have been designed: http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/spores.html

Comment: @cchantep Thanks for your answer, spores can solve the problem of unserializable error of closures, which is my first problem. However, can you give advice for my second question?